# Python Pandas read_csv quote issue, impossible to separate data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with several csv with Pandas. I changed some data name on the original csv file and saved the file. Then, I restarted and reloaded my jupyter notebook but now I got something like this for all dataframe I charged the data source :

```
   Department  Zone    Element     Product     Year    Unit    Value
0   U1,"Z3","ODD 2.a.1...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   U1,"Z3","ODD 2.a.1...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   U1,"Z5","ODD 2.a.1...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   U1,"Z6","ODD 2.a.1...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   U1,"Z9","ODD 2.a.1...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I tried to use `sep=',', encoding='UTF-8-SIG',quotechar='"', quoting=0, engine='python'` but same issue. I don't know how to parse the csv because even when I created a new csv form the data (without the quote and separator as ; ) the same issue appears...

csv is 321 rows, as this example with the problem : https://www.cjoint.com/c/LDCmfvq06R6
and original csv file without problem in Pandas : https://www.cjoint.com/c/LDCmlweuR66

Comment: Have you tried `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` argument to read_csv?

Comment: When I use this I got the error name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: yeah, you need to have `import csv` or `quoting=1`

Comment: with quoting=1 then AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'QUOTE_ALL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing problem with quotes of the file

```
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('LDCmfvq06R6_FAOSTAT.csv', quotechar='"',
                                            delimiter = ',', 
                                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                                            on_bad_lines='skip')
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '')

df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't use the file with mistake. It's the fisrt link https://www.cjoint.com/c/LDCmfvq06R6. The other one is to show the original file, then I modified some data in the original and saved it as a new file (the link above)

Comment: @Lilly_Co you can check now the given answer, the first column quotes missing when you read without quote parameter

Comment: Ok thanks ! So now why this happens with this second file because I just changed a single value from the original csv and save it

Comment: You are wellcome!, I think it can be happen because of your csv file editor, when ı check with excel the error happens again. However, when I check with Sublime Text , the file does not gives error.